# Removing <br /> inside href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a problem removing the 
 tag inside the href attribute of achor tag. Here is the code when i inspect element the site:

```
<a href="mailto:sample-email.com<br />">sample-email.com</a>
```

I tried removing it using this method but nothing happens.

```
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a').attr('href').find('br').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/8RGm2/2/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('a').attr('href', function (_,old) {
        return old.replace('<br />', '');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery('a').attr('href', function(idx, href){
    return href.replace('<br />', '')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8RGm2/)

Answer (score 3):

jquery [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) is part of the DOM traversal API.

In the HTML example you pasted, `<br />` is part of the href attribute string. Find will not work on it, as the `<br>` tag isn't in the DOM, but erroneously in the string.

You'll need to replace `<br /`>` with an empty string, using basic string manipulation.

```
jQuery('a').attr('href', function(i, str){
    return str.replace('<br />', '');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').attr('qttr', function(index, oldAttr){
    return oldAttr.replace(/\<br\s?\/\>/, "");
});
```

Note that I would have remove that nonsense `<br>` from the beginning.